# change display of rows into single row in SQL server 2008 using dynamic PIVOTS

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have 2 tables -

```
USE [Test1July]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Hotels](
    [SeqID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [HotelName] [nchar](25) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Hotels] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SeqID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

USE [Test1July]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[hpt_HotelRooms](
    [SEQ_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [HotelSEQ_ID] [int] NULL,
    [FloorNo] [int] NULL,
    [RoomNo] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Beds] [int] NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [SharingType] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [PaxType] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NULL,
    [DisplayOrder] [smallint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_hpt_Rooms] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SEQ_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[hpt_HotelRooms]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_hpt_HotelRooms_Hotels] FOREIGN KEY([HotelSEQ_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Hotels] ([SeqID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[hpt_HotelRooms] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_hpt_HotelRooms_Hotels]
GO
```

I have been successful in generating the desired results by pivoting - Here's the query that I have developed.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @HotelSeqID AS INT

        SET @HotelSeqID = 1


select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col + '_' + cast(seq as varchar(2))) 
                    from
                    (
                      select seq = row_number() over(partition by h.SeqID, r.FloorNo
                                                      order by r.RoomNo) 
                      from dbo.Hotels h
                      inner join dbo.hpt_HotelRooms r
                        on h.seqid = r.HotelSEQ_ID
                        WHERE h.SeqID = @HotelSeqID                  
                    ) d
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'RoomNo', 1 union all
                      select 'Beds', 2
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by col, so, seq
                    order by seq, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT SeqID, FloorNo, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select hr.SeqID, 
                hr.FloorNo, 
                col = c.col + ''_'' + cast(seq as varchar(2)),
                c.val
              from
              (
                select h.SeqID, 
                  r.FloorNo,
                  r.RoomNo,
                  r.Beds,
                  seq = row_number() over(partition by h.SeqID, r.FloorNo
                                          order by r.RoomNo) 
                from dbo.Hotels h
                inner join dbo.hpt_HotelRooms r
                  on h.seqid = r.HotelSEQ_ID
                  WHERE h.seqid = ' + CONVERT ( NVARCHAR , @HotelSeqID, 2 ) + '

              ) hr
              cross apply
              (
                select ''RoomNo'', RoomNo union all
                select ''Beds'', Beds
              ) c (col, val)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(val)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 

            order by SeqID, FloorNo'

exec sp_executesql @query
```

It works fine but when I try to add other columns in it - It gives me conversion errors - Why is that so and what could be best possible workaround of it.

Here is my query that I am trying to fix

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @HotelSeqID AS INT

        SET @HotelSeqID = 1


select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col + '_' + cast(seq as varchar(2))) 
                    from
                    (
                      select seq = row_number() over(partition by h.SeqID, r.FloorNo
                                                      order by r.RoomNo) 
                      from dbo.Hotels h
                      inner join dbo.hpt_HotelRooms r
                        on h.seqid = r.HotelSEQ_ID
                        WHERE h.SeqID = @HotelSeqID                  
                    ) d
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'RoomNo', 1 union all
                      select 'Beds', 2 union all
                      select '[Description]',3 union all
                      select 'SharingType',4 union all
                      select 'PaxType',5
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by col, so, seq
                    order by seq, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT SeqID, FloorNo, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select hr.SeqID, 
                hr.FloorNo, 
                col = c.col + ''_'' + cast(seq as varchar(2)),
                c.val
              from
              (
                select h.SeqID, 
                  r.FloorNo,
                  r.RoomNo,
                  r.Beds,
                  r.[Description],
                  r.SharingType,
                  r.PaxType,
                  seq = row_number() over(partition by h.SeqID, r.FloorNo
                                          order by r.RoomNo) 
                from dbo.Hotels h
                inner join dbo.hpt_HotelRooms r
                  on h.seqid = r.HotelSEQ_ID
                  WHERE h.seqid = ' + CONVERT ( NVARCHAR , @HotelSeqID, 2 ) + '

              ) hr
              cross apply
              (
                select ''RoomNo'', RoomNo union all
                select ''Beds'', Beds union all
                select ''[Description]'', [Description] union all
                select ''SharingType'', SharingType union all
                select ''PaxType'',5 PaxType
              ) c (col, val)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(val)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 

            order by SeqID, FloorNo'

exec sp_executesql @query
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `CROSS APPLY` or unpivot.  When you unpivot data it will then be placed in the same column so the datatype must be the same.

Your code is using to unpivot is:

```
cross apply
(
  select ''RoomNo'', RoomNo union all
  select ''Beds'', Beds union all
  select ''[Description]'', [Description] union all
  select ''SharingType'', SharingType union all
  select ''PaxType'',5 PaxType
) c (col, val)
```

This process takes these separate columns and places them into a single column.  The problem is that you have different datatypes for each of these columns.  `RoomNo` is a `varchar`, `Beds` in an `int`, `Description` is a `varchar`, `SharingType` in a `nvarchar` and `PaxType` is a `varchar`.

You can fix this but converting the datatype to be the same on all columns.  You can perform this conversion in your subquery or in the `CROSS APPLY`

Subquery:

```
from
(
  select h.SeqID, 
    r.FloorNo,
    r.RoomNo,
    Beds = cast(r.Beds as varchar(10)),  -- cast all columns here
    r.[Description],
    r.SharingType,
    r.PaxType,
    seq = row_number() over(partition by h.SeqID, r.FloorNo
                            order by r.RoomNo) 
  from dbo.Hotels h
  inner join dbo.hpt_HotelRooms r
    on h.seqid = r.HotelSEQ_ID
  WHERE h.seqid = ' + CONVERT ( NVARCHAR , @HotelSeqID, 2 ) + '
) hr
```

Or inside your `CROSS APPLY`:

```
cross apply
(
  select ''RoomNo'', RoomNo union all
  select ''Beds'', cast(Beds as varchar(10)) union all  -- cast all columns here
  select ''[Description]'', [Description] union all
  select ''SharingType'', SharingType union all
  select ''PaxType'',5 PaxType
) c (col, val)
```

Once the data is in the same datatype, then you should no longer get the error.